# ArgumentError: An error occurred parsing (locally or remotely) the arguments to datastore_v3.Put()

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My app started throwing this error last night. Users are complaining the site is slow as well. Still on Python 2.5. As far as I can tell the request itself is not unusual.

Any ideas?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~jupitersfolly/4.357517623694016771/controller/frequest.py", line 57, in post
    request_types[request_type]()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~jupitersfolly/4.357517623694016771/controller/frequest.py", line 78, in order
    event, report, messages = Game.update(game_number, user_id, order)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~jupitersfolly/4.357517623694016771/model/game.py", line 355, in update
    event, report, game, universe, messages, updated, ended = db.run_in_transaction(Game.transactional_update, key_id, user_id, order)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2433, in RunInTransaction
    return RunInTransactionOptions(None, function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2571, in RunInTransactionOptions
    ok, result = _DoOneTry(new_connection, function, args, kwargs)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 2593, in _DoOneTry
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~jupitersfolly/4.357517623694016771/model/game.py", line 348, in transactional_update
    game.put()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 1074, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 604, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1577, in __put_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1212, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 570, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 133, in CheckSuccess
    raise self.exception
    ArgumentError: An error occurred parsing (locally or remotely) the arguments to datastore_v3.Put()
```

Comment: You've chopped the actual exception message off the bottom of your stacktrace.

Comment: opps sorry. it was the title of the post.

Comment: Would be nice to know the model you are putting, and what else is in the transaction.

Comment: The problem seems to have gone, just one evening of errors. I can make my source code available if you want some help tracking down the issue for others. You can email me jay@ironhelmet.com